# Duda al ejecutar script de bash en linux [ERROR]

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell

Me piden a realizar lo siguiente:

Crear un script que:

1. Pida un número al usuario entre el 1 y el 10.
2. Gracias al script anterior compruebe si es un número.
3. Si no es número valido, lo notifica y vuelve a preguntar.
4. Si es un número valido, pase al siguiente punto.
5. Realice la tabla de multiplicar del número y la muestre por pantalla.

Dentro de mi ejecutable .sh, he colocado el siguiente código:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while true;
do
echo "Introduce un número entre el 1 y el 10"
read numero

if [[ $numero -gt 0 && $numero -lt 11 ]]; then

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;
do
echo "$numero x $i = "$(($numero*$i))
done

else
echo "El valor introducido no es un número, inténtelo de nuevo"
fi
done
```

Y me sale el siguiente error cuando lo ejecuto:

```
Introduce un número entre el 1 y el 10

5

script4.sh: 8: script4.sh: 5: not found

El valor introducido no es un número, inténtelo de nuevo
```

Comment: Pues acabo de probar tu código y funciona correctamente :/

Comment: script4.sh: 8: script4.sh: [[: not found - ¿Qué podría ser? es extraño...

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás ejecutando? Pinta que no estás usando bash y hay algunos detalles allí que sólo van a funcionar en bash.

Comment: sh script4.sh, me pide que introduzca el numero y cuando se lo indico me da el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás ejecutándolo explícitamente con bash (y hay detalles como el `[[` que sólo funcionan ahí -son bashismos-).

Asegúrate de usar

`bash miscript.sh`

o

`./miscript.sh`

Siempre dándole permiso de ejecución al archivo. Lo otro que necesitas es añadir `#!/bin/bash`  al comienzo del archivo, pero eso ya lo hiciste.

PD. Yo le pondría algo para que, si le pones 0, cierre el programa o algo. Pues, queda más bonito que cerrar con ctrl+c :)

PD2. Encontré una pregunta donde hay más detalles sobre ésto: [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230690/string-comparison-in-bash-not-found)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema estaba en la ejecución como bien dices. Con bash .sh funciona correctamente. :)

Comment: @José muy bueno saber que pudimos ayudar. Recuerda que puedes marcar la repsuesta como aceptada para que otros sepan en el futuro cuál es la solución al problema.